# while accessing a view through controller CSS is not working

Tags: html, css, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a asp.net mvc application index.cshtml is my default page when i run the application this startup page run with css applied but when i access this page from controller "/home/index" the css is not working what is the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use '/' as prefix in the css path. it consider from the root.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```